Moving Average Filter. General Form of a Filtered Signal. How to Determine the Phase Shift?
Let's consider the following filter $$y[n]=\frac{1}{3}(u[n-2]+u[n-1]+u[n])$$ and $M=3$, $k=\overline{0,2}$ with $$u[n]=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}n\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}n\right)+\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}n\right).$$
Next, I computed the frequency response $z \longrightarrow e^{j\omega}:$
$$H(\omega)=\frac{1}{3}e^{-jw}(2\cos(\omega)+1).$$
Next step was to compute the magnitude phase:
$\left|H(\omega)\right|$.
I have computed the magnitude for each frequency component of the input signal:

For $\displaystyle \omega =\frac{\pi}{10} \Rightarrow \left|H(\omega)\right|=0.967$

For $\displaystyle \omega =\frac{\pi}{4} \Rightarrow \left|H(\omega)\right|=0.805$

For $\displaystyle \omega =\frac{3\pi}{4} \Rightarrow \left|H(\omega)\right|=0.138$


Is it correct to conclude that the filtered signal representation is:
$$y[n]=0.967\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{10}\right)+0.805\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)+0.138\sin\left(\frac{3n\pi}{4}\right)$$
or should be taken into consideration also the phase shift?
If yes, how to determine the phase shift? Or even better how to understand what phase shift is?

You correctly computed the frequency response, but your output signal isn't correct (as you already suspected), because you didn't take the phase shift into account.
The response of an LTI system with frequency response
$$H(\omega)=\big|H(\omega)\big|e^{j\phi(\omega)}\tag{1}$$
to a sinusoidal input $x(t)=\sin(\omega_0t)$ is given by
$$y(t)=\big|H(\omega_0)\big|\sin\big(\omega_0t+\phi(\omega_0)\big)\tag{2}$$
Since the system is linear, the response to a (weighted) sum of sinusoids
$$x(t)=\sum_na_n\sin(\omega_nt)$$
is
$$y(t)=\sum_na_n\big|H(\omega_n)\big|\sin\big(\omega_nt+\phi(\omega_n)\big)$$
The phase shift $\phi(\omega)$ results in a frequency dependent delay $\tau(\omega)=-\phi(\omega)/\omega$:
$$\sin\big(\omega_0t+\phi(\omega_0)\big)=\sin\left(\omega_0\left(t+\frac{\phi(\omega_0)}{\omega_0}\right)\right)=\sin\big(\omega_0\big(t-\tau(\omega_0)\big)\big)$$
This frequency dependent delay $\tau(\omega)$ is referred to as phase delay.

Could you please expand the computation for "The phase shift ϕ(ω)
results in a frequency dependent delay." Thanks!

@danciulian: Please see my edited answer.
